# Does anyone know why my message is not showing in Logcat

Tags: kotlin, intellij-14

I have this code in main

```kotlin
val password = R.id.registerPassword.toString()
Log.d("Message", password)  // password = "12345"
```

but i cant find this message in Logcat

I tried to reset the software, I have also tried to change some setting for Logcat there was no result.

Comment: have you tried to filter in the bottom of Android studio?

Comment: Yes I tires all of the filters